# How do I make my circle rotate in a expanding circle (pattern described with picture) with a given force (Like a beyblade) in unity2D

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

[pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3DuD.png)

How do I make my circle rotate in an expanding circle (pattern described above) with a given force (Like a Beyblade) in unity2D, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Defining the radius of your circle based on the angle of the point you are on the circle can create that pattern. You can expose parameters of that relationship to change the distance between successive rotations.